# make one select query using 2, the queries being operated on the same table

Tags: mysql

Take 2 tables as input - Employee and salary as

```
Employee            Salary  
ID  Name            ID  Salary  
1   Anshika         1   1000  
2   Arnav           2   2000  
3   Ishita          3   3000  
4   Iti             4   4000
```

Display output as--

```
A       I  
3000    7000
```

I've written 2 queries as--

```
    mysql> select sum(salary) as sumA from salEmp where id in (select id from nameEmp where name LIKE 'A%');  

output  

sumA  
3000
```

1 row in set (0.00 sec)

```
    mysql> select sum(salary) as sumI from salEmp where id in (select id from nameEmp where name LIKE 'I%');  

output  

sumI  
7000
```

1 row in set (0.01 sec)

But I want to write a single query so that I can the desired output as in the question.

I tried--

```
mysql> select sum(a.salary) as sumA, sum(b.salary) as sumI
->  from salEmp a,salEmp b
->  where a.id in
->          (select id from nameEmp where name LIKE 'A%')
->  AND b.id in
->          (select id from nameEmp where name LIKE 'I%');
```

but the output is as follows--

```
sumA  sumI  
6000  14000  
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

the values are doubled.
plz help in getting the original output...

Comment: Is it your query - "Get the total salary of the employee whose name starts with 'A' and whose name starts with 'I' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing a [cross join](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/advance-query-in-mysql/mysql-cross-join.php). So the resultant table gets duplicate values.
Instead you can follow the following query :

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN ID IN (SELECT ID FROM nameEmp 
                        WHERE name Like 'A%') THEN Salary ELSE 0 END) AS sumA,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ID IN (SELECT ID FROM nameEmp 
                        WHERE name Like 'I%') THEN Salary ELSE 0 END) AS sumI

FROM salEmp
```

You can learn about "CASE WHEN" from here if you are not familiar with this.

http://www.java2s.com/Code/SQL/Flow-Control/UseCASEWHENstatementinSELECT.htm

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help!!!. I found one more solution for the problem--

```
select a.sumA, b.sumI from   
(select sum(salary) as sumA from salEmp where id in (select id from nameEmp where name LIKE 'A%')) a,
(select sum(salary) as sumI from salEmp where id in (select id from nameEmp where name LIKE 'I%')) b;
```